# Sending SMS text with line break/new line

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am developing SMS portal in asp.net c# where people register & send sms.
I M Using multiline asp:textbox for input message. i want to break line where user hit enter/new line in textbox. help me if there any textboxeditor which support only  `<br/>` or any other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from my own experience the default **asp:textbox** control  with  **TextBoxMode=MultiLine**;  which automatically adds \r\n for line breaks will do the trick and **no additional edit is needed**
and html tags like `</br>` is not  processed .

Answer (score 2):

Use [textarea](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_textarea.asp) tag and escape text on the server side. Replace each line break with `</br>`, but other tags show as plain text or add some validation.